# Selenium/Python browser loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a basic script written in Python to check a div and click a button. I auto reload using `browser.implicitly_wait` but then how do I get it to loop through the code without duplicating it?

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('sitediv'); elem.send_keys('Red' + Keys.RETURN);

browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear with what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to it keep running/looping the code

Comment: If you want to address a particular condition, use `while <condition>` or if you want to iterate for a particular number of times use `for _1 in <number_of_iterations>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation about loops in python all over the Internet.

Here's a sample :

- http://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm
- http://sthurlow.com/python/lesson04/

Have a good reading!

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what are you waiting.

Here is an example to wait that an element appears on the page with `while` and `_is_visible` function to check if the element exists on the page :

```python
class DockerContainerDeployer(object):

    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def deploy(self)
        # actions...
        # wait until the docker container is deployed 
        # by checking a div that give us the status
        while not self._is_visible("#cluster-status .deployed"):
            # you can add an implicity wait to check it every 10s with
            # self.browser.implicitly_wait(10)
            pass
        # docker container deployed

    def _is_visible(self, locator, timeout = 2):
        """
        Check if an element is visible
        """

        try:
            ui.WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, locator)))
            return True
        except TimeoutException:
            return False
```